# Why do I get a ValueError when using CrossEntropyLoss

Tags: python, neural-network, pytorch

I am trying to train a pretty simple 2-layer neural network for a multi-class classification class. I am using `CrossEntropyLoss` and I get the following error: `ValueError: Expected target size (128, 4), got torch.Size([128])` in my training loop at the point where I am trying to calculate the loss.

My last layer is a softmax so it outputs the probabilities of each of the 4 classes. My target values are a vector of dimension `128` (just the class values). Am I initializing the `CrossEntropyLoss` object incorrectly?

I looked up existing posts, this one seemed the most relevant:
https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/valueerror-expected-target-size-128-10000-got-torch-size-128-1/29424 However, if I had to `squeeze` my target values, how would that work? Like right now they are just class values for e.g., `[0 3 1 0]`. Is that not how they are supposed to look? I would think that the loss function maps the highest probability from the last layer and associates that to the appropriate class index.

Details:

1. This is using PyTorch
2. Python version is 3.7
3. NN architecture is: embedding -> pool -> h1 -> relu -> h2 -> softmax
4. Model Def (EDITED):

```
self.embedding_layer = create_embedding_layer(embeddings)
self.pool = nn.MaxPool1d(1)
self.h1 = nn.Linear(embedding_dim, embedding_dim)
self.h2 = nn.Linear(embedding_dim, 4)
self.s = nn.Softmax(dim=2)
```

```
forward pass:
    x = self.embedding_layer(x)
    x = self.pool(x)
    x = self.h1(x)
    x = F.relu(x)
    x = self.h2(x)
    x = self.s(x)
    return x
```

Comment: What are the shapes of your target and logit vectors?

Comment: Based on the error, your model output probably has an extra dimension. Like `(128, D, 4)` instead of `(128, 4)` which is what you likely want.

Comment: Could you provide your model definition?

Comment: The target vector is basically a batch_size-vector, so 128 in this case. The target is just the corresponding class.

Comment: @adeelh Yes, it does. The dimension is 128, D, 4. That D comes from the length of the input vector (batch_size x D). How would one go about transforming from 128 x D x 4 to 128 x 4?

Comment: It seems strange that you end up with `(128, D, 4)`. *"D comes from the length of the input vector"*, did you mean to say *sequence length*?

Comment: Sorry, that's what I meant - sequence length.

Comment: And you aren't using any RNN in your model?

Comment: Nope, I added some more details in the post regarding the model.

Comment: I think I figured out the issue, instead of max pooling, I need to do a sum pooling. So, essentially, reducing the `128 x D x 4` to `128 x embedding_dim`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that the output of your model is a tensor shaped as `(batch, seq_length, n_classes)`. Each sequence element in each batch is a four-element tensor corresponding to the predicted probability associated with each class (`0`, `1`, `2`, and `3`). Your target tensor is shaped `(batch,)` which is usually the correct shape (you didn't use one-hot-encodings). However, in this case, you need to provide a target for **each** one of the sequence elements.

Assuming the target is the same for each element of your sequence (this might not be true though and is entirely up to you to decide), you may repeat the targets `seq_length` times. [`nn.CrossEntropyLoss`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss.html) allows you to provide additional axes, but you have to follow a specific shape layout:

> - Input: (N, C) where C = number of classes, or (N, C, d_1, d_2, ..., d_K) with K≥1 in the case of K-dimensional loss.
> - Target: (N) where each value is 0 ≤ targets[i] ≤ C−1 , or (N, d_1, d_2, ..., d_K) with K≥1 in the case of K-dimensional loss.

In your case, `C=4` and `seq_length` (what you referred to as `D`) would be `d_1`.

```
>>> seq_length = 10
>>> out = torch.rand(128, seq_length, 4) # mocking model's output
>>> y = torch.rand(128).long()           # target tensor

>>> criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()

>>> out_perm = out.permute(0, 2, 1)
>>> out_perm.shape
torch.Size([128, 4, 10])  # (N, C, d_1)

>>> y_rep = y[:, None].repeat(1, seq_length)
>>> y_rep.shape
torch.Size([128, 10])     # (N, d_1)
```

Then call your loss function with `criterion(out_perm, y_rep)`.

Comment: Ah, this was key: "Assuming the target is the same for each element of your sequence (this might not be true though and is entirely up to you to decide), you may repeat the targets `seq_length` times".

Okay, I think I just made the error of not reducing the dimension down (in this case by summing the embedding for each element in the sequence).

But your answer makes great sense, thank you!